# Evento load dentro de evento load?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Eu preciso do primeiro load pra resolver o problema do autoload dos scripts que eu faço com php aonde eu não consigo definir a ordem em que eles vão ser carregados, e depois disso eu preciso dentro desse load de outro load. É possível usar um evento load dentro de outro evento load?

```
INDEX.HTML
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <?php
      $scripts = dir("js");
      while ($script = $scripts->read()) if ($scripts != "." && $scripts != "..") echo "<script src='js/{$script}'></script>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Aí eu tenho os arquivos carta.js, funcoes.js, script.js e texto.js.
carta e texto são classes, funcoes tem um monte de funcoes que eu uso no programa e o script depende desses arquivos ja estarem lidos pra funcionar.

```
SCRIPT.JS
```

```css
const cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
cosnt ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
const imgs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (imgs[i] = new Image()).src = `img/imagem${i}.png`;
}
window.onload = () => {
    // executa o resto
}
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que tens? assim podemos encontrar uma outra solução que seja mais adequada

Comment: Ok, vou editar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gera uma array com esses scripts e depois faz um loader no JavaScript assim:

```js
<script>
const scripts = [
<?php
  $scripts = dir("js");
  while ($script = $scripts->read()) if ($scripts != "." && $scripts != "..") echo $script.",";
?>
];


function loadScript(src, done) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'ajaxnotxt.txt';
  script.onload = done
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function carregarScripts(scripts, done) {
  let carregados = 0;
  scripts.forEach((script) => {
    loadScript(script, () => {
      carregados++;
      if (carregados == scripts.length) done();
    });
  });
}

carregarScripts(scripts, () => {
  // aqui todos os scripts estão carregados
  const cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
  const imgs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (imgs[i] = new Image()).src = `img/imagem${i}.png`;
  }

  // executa o resto

});
```